# Migraciones Laravel con longitud en campos text

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Si en una ***migración en Laravel se indica una longitud máxima*** en un campo de tipo *TEXT*... ***¿tiene algún efecto en la estructura de la tabla?***

Por ejemplo:

```
$table->text('internal_notes', 400)->nullable();
```

Las migraciones se ejecutan correctamente (Laravel 7), sin embargo en una ***BD MySql*** esto creo que no tiene ningún efecto. Creo que sí podría ser así en otros SGDBD, ¿saben algo de esto?

Comment: A que te refieres con ¿"efecto en la estructua"? Que no se va crear con la longitud dada?

Comment: @JuanRivera la migración se ejecuta y la tabla se crea. Estoy usando una BD MySql, no he visto que el campo tenga una longitud concreta, puedes introducir un texto de la longitud que sea, dentro de los límites del tipo de campo. Por ejemplo puedo escribir un texto de 5ooo caracteres... No se si el límite afecta a otras BD.

Comment: En teoria son muy independientes los campos que se definen con respecto a otras BD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tipo TEXT generado por el [blueprint builder $table->text('campo')](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-text)` solamente recibe **un** parámetro. Al igual que en incontables ejemplos, los parámetros extra que le pases al método son ignorados y no saltan errores ni warnings.

Este comportamiento permitía definir [funciones variádicas](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) (ej: aceptan un número variable de argumentos) cuando no existían los [rest parameters que datan de PHP 5.6](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics),  y se acostumbraba recorrer los argumentos recibidos con [func_get_args](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args). Tiene otras aplicaciones y en muchos casos puede ser útil, pero en general ese branching en tiempo de ejecución es un impedimento para el análisis estático y es mejor evitarlo.

Hoy en dia muchas funciones nativas y o métodos de clases nativas reclaman cuando las invocas con parámetros extra

```
echo (new DateTime())->format('Ymd',2);
PHP Warning:  DateTime::format() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in php shell code on line 1
```

Pero las clases de terceros evitan este comportamiento por temas de retrocompatibilidad

```
 echo (new \Carbon\Carbon())->format('Ymd',2);
 // imprime 20210114
```

En este ejemplo, por debajo Carbon sólo verifica que hayas pasado suficientes parámetros y luego delega en la clase DateTime sólo con los parámetros necesarios. Lo que le hayas pasado extra no pasa de ahí.

Comment: Esta clase de respuestas no solo son buenas por que responden la duda si no que dan contexto por ejemplo del lenguaje, como siempre excelente +1